# C# - Default font Times New Roman won't display in PDF with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, fonts, itext, font-face

I'm trying to change the font from Arial to a default font Times New Roman.
I tried different solutions, but none of them helped!

The original code was:

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, file);
System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
writer.SetEncryption();
doc.Open();
FontFactory.Register(
    "C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\ARIALUNI.TTF", "arial unicode ms");
iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet ST =
    new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet();
ST.LoadTagStyle("body", "encoding", "Identity-H"); `
```

I'm testing this code for the Times New Roman:

```
FontFactory.Register(
     "C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Times New Roman\\times.tff",
     "times new roman regular");
iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet ST =
    new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet();
ST.LoadTagStyle("body", "face", "times new roman");
ST.LoadTagStyle("body", "encoding", "Identity-H");
```

Comment: Please read the intro of the [HTML to PDF tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml) and you'll understand why no one cares about your frustration: you are using `HTMLWorker`, a class that has been **abandoned many years ago**. You should upgrade to [iText 7](https://itextpdf.com/itext-7-core) and the [pdfHTML add-on](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfHTML).

Comment: @BrunoLowagie it doesn't depend on me. It is a work specification. I can't make much changes.

Comment: Let me talk to your project manager. You know where to find me. You are actually telling me that your specification is to do a bad job. If you want to do a good job, help me help you. I will talk to whoever makes you do a bad job and convince that person to allow you to do a good job. I can do that. My rank is higher than your project manager. The alternative is failing to do your job...

Comment: Any progress? Did you get a chance to talk to your boss?